# regular expression for css keyframes

Tags: regex

Please help me to make regexp to search for a kind of this:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes chetyre { 
    75%, 100% { color:rgba( 76, 98, 113, 0); visibility: visible; }
    76%, 99% { color:rgba( 76, 98, 113, 1); }
    0%, 74% { visibility: hidden; } }
```

Comment: Search for what exactly?

Comment: for a string  @-webkit-keyframes chetyre { 
    75%, 100% { color:rgba( 76, 98, 113, 0); visibility: visible; }
    76%, 99% { color:rgba( 76, 98, 113, 1); }
    0%, 74% { visibility: hidden; } } in my css

Comment: In general case, it can be other css properties, but string ends with ;}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
.*\{.*;\}\}
```